# Passing Parameters in JSP to Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have following code

**JSP**

```
         <tbody>
            <c:forEach var="defect" items="${defects}">
                <tr>
                    <td>${defect.name}</td>
                    <td>${defect.description}</td>
                    <td>${defect.summary}</td>
                    <td>${defect.priority}</td>
                    <td>${defect.originator.name}</td>
                    <td>${defect.assignee.name}</td>
                    <td>
                        <form action="AllOpenDefects?defectId=${defect.id}" method="get">
                            <input type="submit" value="Update" />
                        </form> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
```

**Servlet** (in doGet method)

```
System.out.println((String) request.getParameter("defectId")); // It is printing null
```

and also in url the `defectId` is **NOT** been appended ... Is there any issue with my code?

**EDIT:** The url is `http://localhost:8080/BugManagemetSystem/AllOpenDefects` but it should be like `http://localhost:8080/BugManagemetSystem/AllOpenDefects?defectId=2`

Comment: "in url the defectId is NOT been appended". What does the URL look like then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your browser clears parameters after `?...` in `action="..."` attribute. In that case try passing it via `<input type="hidden" .../>` like

```
<form action="AllOpenDefects" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="defectId" value="${defect.id}"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
```

This way form should add them to URL as `?defectId`=`value of ${defect.id}`.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the short answer to your question is "your code is ok".

As a side note, if it doesn't yield the new required link, it's often an update problem. E.g. try changing the URL algtogether just for testing (form action="Junk"), see if the browser catches it.
If not, try clearing various caches - browser cache, deleting the exploded war and work directories (e.g. in Tomcat it's /webapps/myapp/  and  /work)...

Comment: This is a comment. Not an answer.

Comment: rephrased as an answer